# How are these methods like create_table available in the Rails Migration class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is a question about how methods and classes are defined in Ruby, and how to read the API docs. In short: how is the `create_table` method defined/imported/inherited so it is available in `ActiveRecord::Migration`, in code like this:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      ...
```

Coming from Java world, I expected the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) to provide links to base classes or mixins where everything was defined. But if I look at the page for `Migration`, I see some helpful hand written docs, but no link to the most detailed, authoritative definition of `create_table`.  I used google to find it in `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements`, but even looking at the source code for the two files:

[Migration in git](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d68e299167c8da07dc63a55197313b5c3396c3a4/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb)
[create_table in git](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fa34acec20574699c2de19d97f9ae54f540fe69d/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb)

I don't see how `create_table` is brought into scope in the `Migration`.

Answer (score 1):

These methods are created dynamically in this class: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d68e299167c8da07dc63a55197313b5c3396c3a4/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration/command_recorder.rb

They are adding those dynamically in the `CommandRecorder` class, then this lines:

```
class Migration
    autoload :CommandRecorder, 'active_record/migration/command_recorder'
```

makes it available to the migration class.

Comment: I think these methods are being defined only inside the class CommandRecorder with class eval.

Comment: @Kaeros thanks for the correction, was viewing it from my phone. I edited accordingly.

Comment: Doesn't that load CommandRecorder under Migration? So I can say `Migration::CommandRecorder.new.create_table` but not `Migration.new.create_table`.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing just now. From the source code (and what I can get out of it) it looks like `CommandRecorder` stores the symbol of each method called, so that in `CommandRecorder` a call to `:create_table` just adds this symbol to the array `@commands`. In this way all methods called in the `Migration` instance are called “through” `CommandRecorder` to store them, but I too can’t see how the `create_table` implementation from `schema_statements.rb` is called from `Migration`.